# Search field - pre populate automatically with user location

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I've seen some website, once you on the front page, it automatically populate the search field with your location. I want to implement the same thing for my directory site.  One field, is for whatever they want to search for, and the second field is a location field for the user to enter the city or postcode they want to search on.

I want to pre-populate the location field, automatically once the user landed on front page.  Any modules that I can use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on which search engine/backend you use. Using Solr, you can use the [Geolocation Field](http://%20https://www.drupal.org/project/geolocation) module in conjunction with [Search API Location](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_location).

The Search API Location module adds the possibility of location based searching to the Search API module (currently only Apache Solr is supported as the service class).

Geolocation Field provides a field type to store geographical locations as pairs of latitude and longitude (lan,lng) as well as the necessary integration to display those locations through views, fields and using a number of different map providers.

Once configured, you will be able to pre-populate the location field by hooking into your search form using [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x).